# Connect Reactjs to ASP.net Core 6 Web API on the same server

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

`REACT_APP_API_URL` is `localhost:4260` on my dev machine

when i run `dotnet run api.dll` it defaults to 5000, so I build of react with `5000` and run both processes on the server, it doesn't connect.

It does work, however if on the client machine I have visual studio running on debug mode and it's using port `5000`.

I've tried tutorials online, follow all the steps but I get no success. Works on local, just not server.

Comment: I am surprised that you got no replies to this! Have you figured it out yourself?